How to avoid data loss with File.rename in Dart / Flutter?
Future<File> File.rename(String newPath)
doc: If [newPath] identifies an existing file or link, that entity is removed first. If [newPath] identifies an existing directory, the operation fails and the future completes with a [FileSystemException].

Data loss is something I want to avoid at all costs. from my understanding File.rename will result in a Data loss if newPath already exists.
How can I avoid the possibility of data loss?

so you want to make sure that you will not overwrite the existing file? cannot you first check if the target already exists?

@pskink that could result in a race condition. the file creation can appear in between the check and the move operation.

Can't be a race condition if you use the sync versions of test and rename, unless you're also running the same code in multiple isolates.
